# Unique identifier of websocket messages

Tags: websocket

I am trying to figure out if there is an in-built unique identifier of messages that websocket generates. Each websocket exposes the following paramter,  ws._socket._handle.fd to uniquely identify a socket. Similarly is there an identifier for every message?

I am using ws library for managing websockets. Currently I am making up my own id inside the message body.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Which programming language and framework are you using? Please appropriate tags to reach the target audience.

Comment: Hmm... No. `fd` is **not** _safely_ unique and **shouldn't** be used to identify a connection. Once a connection is disconnected, the `fd` is recycled and used for future connections.

Comment: Oh, and the Websocket protocol does **not** include a message identification system. There's no unique message ID as part of the protocol (although there may be one as part of your framework).

Comment: Hi StephenKing Thank you for your response. I am using javascript(nodejs and ws library). What is the right way to identify a connection if fd is not unique? Also if I detect a disconnect(I am hoping I can) and kill my references to this connection id in my app, will it not solve the problem of non-unique ids?